# Javascript array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to have an array containing an object. For example I have an object like this:

```
parentObj:{
    childObj1,
    childObj2
}
```

but I want to have a "parentObj" array and be able to call it like :

```
parentObj[0].childObj1
```

I searched a lot but didn't find anything related to this. I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
thanks very much

Comment: That first line isn't valid JS, can you fix it?

Comment: [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: @Dennis: But it will be in ES6, if it's inside an object initializer. :-) In ES6, `var o = {foo, bar};` is equivalent to `var o = {foo: foo, bar: bar};`.

Comment: Why two minus points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an array of objects:

```
var a = [
    {name: "first"},
    {name: "second"}
];

console.log(a[0].name); // "first"
console.log(a[1].name); // "second"
```

The `[]` is an array initializer. The `{}` is an object initializer.

Comment: is there any way to not initializing the "name"?

Comment: @m0j1: You can create empty objcts with `{}`. You can't have an object with a property that has no value; but you can have one with a property whose value is `undefined`: `{name: undefined}`.

Comment: it worked but I also tried something like var a=[][{name:"first,last:"last"}]; to create two dimensional array and address it like a[0][1].name but seems it doesn't work. can you also give me an example of two dimensionals in this case? thanks

Comment: @m0j1: Please read some basic JavaScript tutorials. It will be *dramatically* more efficient than this.